# How to post data with body as shown and pass to get response in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, parsing, swift3, http-post

Here i need to send the raw data response to the server so that in order to get the data from server to display and in this quote_id,sku and qty are changeable can anyone help me how to post data with shown below ?

```
{"cartItem":{"quote_id":"fe9304ce6f173aa1876e847571756bc9","sku":"24-MB01","qty":"1"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), then use the following method:

```
let key = "some_key"
let sku = "some sku"
let params: [String: Any] = [
    "cartItem" : [
        "quote_id" : key,
        "sku" : sku,
        ....
    ]
]

// All three of these calls are equivalent
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
```

Comment: but here quoteid ,sku and qty are changeable so how to change dynamically

Comment: let parameters = ["cartItem":
                                [
                                    "quote_id":"\(key)",
                                    "sku":"\(itemCode)",
                                    "qty":"1"
                                ]
                        ]    can i add like this ?